# Does this sequences convergence? $a_{n} = n \cdot \sin(\frac{2}{n})$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Does this sequences convergence for $n \rightarrow \infty$? $$a_{n} =
> n \cdot \sin(\frac{2}{n}) $$?

Very problematic task..

$n$ alone would diverge to $\infty$ and $sin(\frac{2}{n})$ would converge to $0$.

So we got $\infty \cdot 0$ which means we need to use Hôpital's rule.

For use this rule we need fraction: $$\frac{n}{\frac{1}{sin(\frac{2}{n})}}$$

$$\left ( n\right )' = 1$$

$$\left (\frac{1}{sin(\frac{2}{n})} \right )' = \frac{2 cos(\frac{2}{n})}{n^{2} \cdot sin^{2}(\frac{2}{n})}$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{1}{\frac{2 cos(\frac{2}{n})}{n^{2} \cdot sin^{2}(\frac{2}{n})}} = \frac{n^{2} \cdot sin^{2}(\frac{2}{n})}{2 cos(\frac{2}{n})}$$

Problem still remains, $$\frac{\infty^{2} \cdot 0^{2}}{2 \cdot 1}$$

I would just say that the sequence diverges.. No idea what else I can do.

What you think about my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and setting $x=\frac{2}{n}$, we have
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\Big(\frac{2}{n}\Big)=2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{2}{n})}{\frac{2}{n}}=2 $$

For your solution, I imagine something went wrong with the derivatives. I'd suggest turning $n$ into $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}}$ rather than doing the same for the sine term.

Comment: Oh you right I took complicated way and did it wrong too :(
Ty!

Answer (score 4):

$a_n=  2{{ŝin(2/n)}\over {2/n}}$, so $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=2sin'(0)=2cos(0)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put $1/n $ in the denominator:
$$
a_n=\frac{\sin(2/n)}{1/n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$n \to \frac{1}{x}$$

$$\infty \to 0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

Hence it converges.

**Adapt it to yours**

Answer (score 1):

Recall from elementary geometry that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$|x\cos(x)|\le |\sin(x)|\le |x| \tag 1$$

for $|x|\le \pi/2$.  Then, using $(1)$ we can write for $n>1$

$$2\cos(2/n)\le n\sin(2/n)\le 2 \tag 2$$

whence applying the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(2/n)=2$$